# Combo-box data input in Datasheet View in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I need help in creating my first application in MS Access 2007.

Consider a table in MS Access with a column "AgeGroup" and the possible values for this column are "Child" and "Adult". Is there an option in MS Access to enter data into this column using a combo-box with these two values in **Datasheet** view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Simple (but questionable) solution:**

(in strict accordance with OP's question)

1. Create a new table
2. Add the column which you want to control by a combobox and give it a column name and the `Text` type.
3. Make sure that the appropriate column is selected and then click the `Lookup` tab page in the MS Access table designer
4. Change the `Display Control` from `TextBox` to `Combo Box`
5. Select `Row Source Type` = `Value List`
6. Enter the following for `Row Source`: `Child,Adult`

Since you probably want to leverage the fact that MS Access is a relational database, you could also have the have the `Child` and `Adult` alternatives as rows in a separate `AgeCategory` table. In order to connect the rows in this table with your combo box you would have to use other Lookup settings. This I leave as an excercise to you.

**EDIT:** As HansUp is pointing out, it is really not a very good solution define this combo box lookup along with the table definition.

This is probably a better approach for a real world solution:

1. Create your table
2. Create a new form which uses your table as data source
3. Add a combo-box to the form and specify the row sourcing for it
4. Switch the Form to `Datasheet View`. A form in `Datasheet View` looks exactly like the type of row editor which you get when you double-click on a table.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks! Yes, I had the idea of having the values in another table. I'll figure it out.

Comment: I downvoted before reading the edit. I really wish it were possible to reverse a downvote.

Comment: In addition to datasheet forms, queries have field properties that allow you to do a combo box in a query datasheet.

Comment: Hmm. I just want to back out my downvote. I don't want to upvote. There was an edit after my downvote, but it only allows me to change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: What if it's a linked table?

Answer (score 2):

Read [The Evils of Lookup Fields in Tables](http://www.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm)

Instead of creating an evil lookup field in your table, build a form which uses the table (or a query based on the table) as the form's record source.

Add your combo box to the form.  Use a value list or another query as the combo's row source.  Switch the form to datasheet view.  You can also select datasheet for "Default View" on the form's property sheet.

Comment: The actual plan is to use a query to get the list from another table. Since, I was just beginning, I did not even know if it is possible to have a combo-box type of data entry in datasheets. That's why I raised the question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: +1 I totally agree with your suggestion, even though it wasn't exactly what OP asked for.